# How to revert to older version in git

Tags: git, github

On github we are at commit 57d7cb274622f86e586c2595317264f23626e6c5
I want to revert to commit 5798ee7c56efd7e898d3115da6efe3d5e7cddb6c which is several commits before the latest one. Here is what I am doing:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
Head is now at  57d7cb274
$ git status
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$git revert 5798ee7c56efd7e898d3115da6efe3d5e7cddb6c
#On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git status
#On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

But the resulting code is not really at the commit at 5798ee7c56efd7e898d3115da6efe3d5e7cddb6c
What am I missing?

Comment: `git status` saying nothing to commit does not mean the commit is not rolled back.

Comment: Agree with Brandon (+1).  Note that you can (could have now ) also have done `git checkout filename` to reset an individual file (filename).  The command syntax, like many of git's can be non-obvious to some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up `git revert` and `git reset`.

With `git reset` you really throw away all those commits and you result at exactly the given commit.

But `git revert` will actually **add** another commit which does exactly the opposite as the original commit, and therefore reverts that commit.

Using `git reset` is fine for your local repository, but once you pushed your commits other people might already started using those commits for their own work. Therefore you want an explicit revert commit in this case.

Be aware that you need to revert **each** unneeded commit if you want to go the revert way.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for git at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html, git revert creates commits which reverse the specified commit.

Therefore, the reason `git status` says there is nothing to commit after running git revert is that the changes you are looking for were already committed.

I think what you are trying to achieve is done, but your test to see if it worked is flawed.