# Instructions on git

Tags: git

I had a few questions while working with git

1. How to always have the latest version of git repository
2. What rules should be followed in order not to get conflicts with git push
3. Do I need to do synchronization when I clone git repository. (HEAD -> main, origin/main) because         it is not displayed this way during the clone, it is necessary to merge the branches.
4. How to revert to a specific version on a remote server.
5. I have not found a satisfactory answer to my questions on the Internet.

I made a git clone url -> coding -> git add . -> git commit -m "desc" -> git push. my friend too. But after several commits, a file conflict occurred. I solved the problem by merging the local branch with the remote repository. To avoid such problems, how to commit correctly?

Answer (score 1):

3. Try this when you want to synchronize

git fetch upstream ->
git checkout main->
git rebase upstream/main

Answer (score 0):

These are great questions Dias,

1. always be sure to `git pull` prior to working in a repository, especially when working on a team. This will avoid conflicts and the need to merge.
2. This goes in conjunction with your first question. If you pull before working on a repository, you will avoid most of the major conflicts.
3. (please specify synchronization)
4. [Great Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803217/how-to-revert-to-older-version-in-git)

Please let me know what else needs to be clarified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To avoid such problems, how to commit correctly?

Commits have nothing to do with merge conflicts.
It's about changes in the same files your teammates and you contribute.

Sometimes you want to keep both changes in file, sometimes you want to leave only latest version, sometimes earlier.
This is about tracking of working lines within a project. Generally, you have to do it manually;
it is good advice to do `git pull` at the beginning of every working day though.